# ExtJs - Javascript - ComboBox in Grid (Cell editing plugin) - Drop down list behind the Grid/Window

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, grid, behind

I have a grid with cell editing plugin on it. When i click the cell i want to edit, sometimes the dropdown list of the combo box is behind the grid/window (I can not see it, but if i modify the window size i can see the combo box items behind it).

My code looks like this (I have a window which contains this form):

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'form',
    items: [
    me.currentMultipleValuesGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: me.gridStoreToValidate,
        plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1,
            delay: 10
        })],
        listeners: {
            validateedit: function (editor, cell, eOpts) {
                //cell.cancel = true;
            }
        },
        columns: [{
            header: GTR(CLNAME(me), 'colSource.Text', 'Source'),
            dataIndex: 'source',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            dataIndex: 'name',
            header: GTR(CLNAME(me), 'colLinkDestination.Text', 'Link destination'),
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                queryMode: 'local',
                valueField: 'nr',
                displayField: 'name',
                store: me.comboBoxEditorStore,
                listeners: {
                    change: function (thisCmb, newValue, oldValue) {

                    },
                    beforerender: function (thisCmb, eOpts) {

                    }
                }
            },
            flex: 1
        }, {
            dataIndex: 'linkdestination',
            hidden: true
        }]
    })]
}]
```

I think it is a layout problem, so I tried different layouts (anchor and fit) assigned to window, grid or form, with various combinations of them. No success so far. Any ideas? Thank you. I am using Extjs 4.0.7

Comment: this may be a 4.0.7 specific issue. have you tried upgrading?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your answer. I can't upgrade, since i'm stuck with this version at work. I will try by myself with another version, to see if it works. Thank you!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this a while ago. Came back to post the answer, in case someone needs it. It seems it is a Sencha bug, which causes the drop down list to be displayed behind the window, when the window is **modal** (like it was in my case). I managed to make a workaround, by assigning a css class to the drop down list of the combo, by adding this in combo settings :

```
listConfig: { cls: 'clsZIndexMax' }
```

where `clsZIndexMax` is my css class containing `z-index: 100000 !important;`

PS: I had this bug in version 4.0.7, don't know if they already solved it in future versions.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer, I am having this issue with 4.2.2 Except, turning off modal makes it show up more clearly, but still behind the window.